# How can I reuse Orbeon's validation in an external validator?

Tags: orbeon

We are running a separate validation process against a set of multiple Orbeon forms so that we can display a full set of validation messages to the user in one place. We want to use the XPath expressions in `relevant`, `required`, and validation expressions within the form definitions as part of this process rather than duplicating those rules.

Is there a way we can call Orbeon to get the validation messages for a form, including meta data to match those messages with controls?

Alternately, we have tried to take the expressions and process them to work with our data. In our system we are using canonical names for controls which we use to store the data from multiple forms in a single XML structure. For example if we had a form set with two forms with the following fields:

**Form A**

```
now.applicantInformation.individualOrCompany
now.applicantInformation.relationshipToCompanyOrOrganization
now.applicantInformation.areYouTheIndividualThisAuthorizationWillBeIssuedTo
now.agentInformation.agentMailingAddress.addressType
now.agentInformation.agentMailingAddress.additionalAddressInformation
```

**Form B**

```
now.access.presentlyGated
now.access.inspectorHasKey
```

Our resulting data would look similar to this:

```xml
<now>
    <applicantInformation>
        <individualOrCompany>Organization</individualOrCompany>
        <relationshipToCompanyOrOrganization>Agent</relationshipToCompanyOrOrganization>
        <areYouTheIndividualThisAuthorizationWillBeIssuedTo>N</areYouTheIndividualThisAuthorizationWillBeIssuedTo>
    </applicantInformation>
    <agentInformation>
        <agentMailingAddress>
            <addressType>Rural Route</addressType>
            <additionalAddressInformation></additionalAddressInformation>
        </agentMailingAddress>
    </agentInformation>
    <access>
        <presentlyGated>Y</presentlyGated>
        <inspectorHasKey>N</inspectorHasKey>
    </access>
</now>
```

For the field `now.agentInformation.agentMailingAddress.additionalAddressInformation` we have this `relevant` xpath expression:

```
(
  (
     $now.applicantInformation.applicantInformation.individualOrCompany='Organization'
     and $now.applicantInformation.applicantInformation.relationshipToCompanyOrOrganization = ('Agent','Executor_Administrator_Trustee','Friend_Neighbour','Power of Attorney','Representative','Trustee in Bankruptcy')
  )
  or ($now.applicantInformation.applicantInformation.areYouTheIndividualThisAuthorizationWillBeIssuedTo='N')
)
and $now.applicantInformation.agentInformation.agentMailingAddress.addressType='Rural Route'
```

We thought we might be able to convert this to an xpath expression that would work with our data structure, like this:

```
(
  (
     /now/applicantInformation/applicantInformation/individualOrCompany/text() = 'Organization'
     and /now/applicantInformation/applicantInformation/relationshipToCompanyOrOrganization/text() = ('Agent','Executor_Administrator_Trustee','Friend_Neighbour','Power of Attorney','Representative','Trustee in Bankruptcy')
  )
  or (/now/applicantInformation/applicantInformation/areYouTheIndividualThisAuthorizationWillBeIssuedTo/text() = 'N')
)
and /now/applicantInformation/agentInformation/agentMailingAddress/addressType/text() = 'Rural Route'
```

Unfortunately when we run this xpath expression from Java we get an error from this portion of the expression:

```
/now/applicantInformation/applicantInformation/relationshipToCompanyOrOrganization/text() = ('Agent','Executor_Administrator_Trustee','Friend_Neighbour','Power of Attorney','Representative','Trustee in Bankruptcy')
```

The error is:

```
expected ) but found ,
```

It seems that the the `/element/text() = ('a','b','c')` syntax is not supported by standard xpath. Is Orbeon able to support this by using XQuery or XForms?

We can convert this to use the OR operator but it is a bit ugly to do that:

`/now/applicantInformation/applicantInformation/relationshipToCompanyOrOrganization[text() = 'Agent' or text() = 'Executor_Administrator_Trustee' or text() = 'Friend_Neighbour' or text() = 'Power of Attorney' or text() = 'Representative' or text() = 'Trustee in Bankruptcy' ]`

We also have expressions that use functions such as `days-from-duration`. XPath has a `days-from-duration` function, but this appears to be different from the one used by Orbeon. An example expression is:

`days-from-duration(($nda.technicalInformation.startAndEndDate.endDate) - ($nda.technicalInformation.startAndEndDate.startDate)) > 0`

Comment: How do you call it from Java? I assume you are not using Saxon's XPath 2 processor? If XPath 1 then you won't be able to do much because XPath 1 is antique. Even parentheses as you are using in your expression there won't work with XPath 1.

Comment: By the way, in XPath 2 you almost *never* need to use `text()`. So for example `foo/text() = ('bar', 'baz')` can be replaced with `foo = ('bar', 'baz')` or `foo/string() = ('bar', 'baz')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to run XPath expressions which run in Orbeon Forms from your own Java code, you will have to use the same XPath processor used in Orbeon Forms, and the same XPath function library. The alternative is to reinvent the wheel, and that will be very difficult.

Orbeon Forms has some abstractions for calling XPath, such as [`XPathCache`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/util/XPathCache.scala) and [`XPath`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/util/XPath.scala). At this point this hasn't been designed to be used by third-party code outside of Orbeon Forms, so some work might be needed there.

Still, you could try to use that, or at the very least to use the Saxon XPath processor to get as close as possible.

Idealy, a form validation service would be offered as part of Orbeon Forms, and leverage existing validation code, but that's a new feature (see also [#1357](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1357)).